# I am unable to launch my Flutter Application due to some Graddle issue

Tags: android, flutter, dart, build.gradle, flutter-dependencies

When i debug the Application, following lines are displayed on the debug console.
The system cannot find the path specified.
Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Is there a way to fix this error? I have tried upgrading flutter and SDK as well but it didn't quiet work out for me.

Comment: if you didn't modify anything in `android` directory, try deleting it and executing `flutter create .` in root directory to recreate the android configurations

Answer (score 0):

Most probably an issue in the Android folder. You can delete the android folder like what eeqk said, then run this

`flutter create . --platforms=android`

This will recreate the android folder.